# How to disable update on a QQuickItem

Tags: c++, qt, qml, scenegraph, qquickitem

I have a `QQuickItem` derived class

```
// Class
class MyQQuickItem : public QQuickItem {
  Q_OBJECT
}

// updatePaintNode in cpp function
QSGNode * MyQQuickItem::updatePaintNode(QSGNode * oldNode, UpdatePaintNodeData * updatePaintNodeData) {

  // draw UI logic
  return node;
}

// QML component
MyQQuickItem {
  id: my_quick
  objectName: "myquickitem"
  width : 500
  height : 500
}
```

I am doing something on a separate UI which causes the `updatePaintNode` of `MyQQuickItem` to be fired. If I have a pointer to MyQQuickItem on cpp side like so,

```
QQuickItem * my_quick_item_ptr = m_qml_engine->rootObjects()[0]->findChild<QQuickItem*>("myquickitem");
```

**How can disable `MyQQuickItem`'s updatePaintNode from getting called when I don't want it to?**
*Secondary question:* If yes, How to reinstate it back again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If and when `updatePaintNode()` is called is most likely scenegraph internal stuff that wasn't really intended to be modified.

Maybe try doing something less invasive like:

```
QSGNode * MyQQuickItem::updatePaintNode(QSGNode * oldNode, UpdatePaintNodeData * updatePaintNodeData) {
  if (doNotUpdate) return oldNode; 
  // draw UI logic
  return node;
}
```

Comment: is there something in the `QQuickItem` class to do this? rather than using my own  `doNotUpdate` based flag management?

Comment: I doubt it will have flags to facilitate non-existent functionality ;) It's just one extra property, which you might as well do since you are extending the class anyway. There is a chance this might not work as expected, I just gave it as an idea, go ahead and try it and report the result, so I can delete the answer if it is no good.